# SimpleDateFormat - Timezone not correct

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a problem in parsing timestampls in Java.

I would expect to have both timestamps in the same timezone (CET).

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdaf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    String str = "30.03.2013 06:00:00";
    sdaf.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone ("CET"));
    java.util.Date dat = sdaf.parse (str);
    System.out.println (str + " = " + dat);

    str = "31.03.2013 05:00:00";
    sdaf.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone ("CET"));
    dat = sdaf.parse (str);
    System.out.println (str + " = " + dat);
```

But that is not the case - see the output.

```
30.03.2013 06:00:00 = Sat Mar 30 06:00:00 CET 2013
31.03.2013 05:00:00 = Sun Mar 31 05:00:00 CEST 2013
```

**EDIT:**

If I change CET with GMT+1 I get this.

```
 03.2013 06:00:00 = Sat Mar 30 06:00:00 CET 2013
 31.03.2013 05:00:00 = Sun Mar 31 06:00:00 CEST 2013
```

Seems to be correct. But why is CET not working?

UTC+1 produces

```
30.03.2013 06:00:00 = Sat Mar 30 07:00:00 CET 2013
31.03.2013 05:00:00 = Sun Mar 31 07:00:00 CEST 2013
```

what is different to GMT+1 - ????

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. I also recommend you avoid relying on three and four letter time zone abbreviations. They are not standardized, hence ambiguous, and many, including CET, are not true time zones, as already explained in [AxelH’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289334/5772882).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get a `CET` time zone for the *31.03.2013 05:00:00* because it was not on that timezone anymore. To understand, just check the name of both timezone

- CET : *Central European Time* (`UTC+1` or `GMT+1`)
- CEST : *Central European Summer Time* (`UTC+2` or `GMT+2`)

That's the Saving Daylight Time that occured during the 31.03.2013 at 02:00:00. So you can't get a `CET` timezone for the second date since it is on the summer "time zone".

If you parse `31.03.2013 02:00:00` you will get

> 31.03.2013 02:00:00 = Sun Mar 31 03:00:00 CEST 2013

Because at 02:00:00 that day, the saving daylight time happened and it became 03:00:00.

You can check that using `TimeZone.inDaylightTime(Date)`

```
String str = "30.03.2013 06:00:00";
java.util.Date dat = sdaf.parse (str);
System.out.println (str + " = " + dat);
System.out.println("SDT : " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET").inDaylightTime(dat));
```

> 30.03.2013 06:00:00 = Sat Mar 30 06:00:00 CET 2013
>   SDT : false

```
str = "31.03.2013 02:00:00";
dat = sdaf.parse (str);
System.out.println (str + " = " + dat);
System.out.println("SDT : " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET").inDaylightTime(dat));
```

> 31.03.2013 02:00:00 = Sun Mar 31 03:00:00 CEST 2013
>   SDT : true

Since `CET` is the same as `UTC+1` or `GMT+1` and `CEST` become `UTC+2` or `GMT+2`, when you force the date to be on `GMT+1`, you get the equivalent of the `CET` but without taking into account the SDT parameter.

Note : This is one of the reason `LocalDateTime` don't bother with `TimeZone` for most of the processing.

Answer (score 2):

[AxelH’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289334/5772882) is correct. Thus I don’t think you really want Central European (Standard) Time for your date-time on 31st March.

I should like to make three other points:

- You should never rely on any three or four letter time zone abbreviation, like CET.
- If you really want Central European Time, it *is* possible since two African countries use CET all year, Algeria and Tunesia.
- Avoid the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date` and use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead.

So my code suggestion is:

```
    ZoneId cetAllYear = ZoneId.of("Africa/Algiers");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter demoFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT);

    String str = "31.03.2013 05:00:00";
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter).atZone(cetAllYear);
    System.out.println (str + " = " + dateTime 
                            + " = " + dateTime.format(demoFormatter));
```

Output:

> 31.03.2013 05:00:00 = 2013-03-31T05:00+01:00[Africa/Algiers] = Sun Mar 31 05:00:00 CET 2013

The same is possible with Africa/Tunis time zone.

**Avoid three letter time zone abbreviations.** Central European Time is a common name for the standard time at offset +01:00 used 5 months of the year in a large number of European time zones. So in one way it’s only half a time zone, in another way it’s many, and you don’t know which one you get. And even less so when you give a date-time that falls in the summer time (DST time of the year). Very many three and four letter abbreviations are ambiguous. Instead give time zone as for example Europe/Rome or Africa/Tunis, as *region*/*city*.

**Avoid `SimpleDateFormat` and its outdated friends.** That class is notoriously troublesome. `java.time` is so much nicer to work with.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Central European Time on timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 and it is more clear and simple than this one.

```
DateTimeFormatter parse = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.XXX");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2013,3,30);
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(6,0);

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, localTime);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("CET"));

System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(parse));
```

Output : 30.03.2013 06:00:00.+01:00

Comment: I am considering upvoting for the helpful use of `java.time`, but hesitating because you are still using the unfortunate three letter time zone abbreviation CET. Those abbreviations are generally ambiguous and often not true time zones. Please avoid them.